# Why Windows Apps not opening and Windows Doesn't Remember Anything About the Settings?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Recently, it has been seen that whenever I open any Windows App, i**t doesn't open and instead minimizes on my PC with NO icon at all! And when I click to that in the taskbar, it maximizes with just the minimize and close button just for a second! However, their live tiles in the Start have been working fine**, and updates too when connected to the internet.

[image: https://fud.community.services.support.microsoft.com/Fud/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?fid=3a973a9f-9d61-4452-9094-f2faaaabbdce]

Secondly, **whenever I open 'This PC', it always opens in restored view. And as I've set documents to be shown in 'Large Views', it always lists the files folders as 'list view' (that is, the default!).** I've also set some files to be sorted 'By Modified', bu it sorts in the default manner, i.e., by name.

It seems form the above event that the file(s) that store(s) these information are corrupt. And as 'PC Settings' app is also not opening, I can't fix/restore my PC! I tried to run the 'sfc /scannow' command, it also didn't fix my problem. It says that it couldn't fix some of the problems, I got to check the log (something like that...). The sfc log can be seen at: http://1drv.ms/1DrcRyJ

If there's something that can be done except reinstalling Windows, please do help me with it.

Comment: Please include your sfc log **in the question**.

Comment: @DavidPostill as the log is too long, so I couldn't include that. I have uploaded that on my OneDrive account. Kindly check that.

Comment: you have the well known **CNBJ2530.DPB** issue. run DISM to fix it: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx